# DWITHIN ECQL query of WFS is not working properly

Tags: geoserver, wfs, filter, getfeature

I don't know where I am making mistake. And my URL is returning all values of the feature layer:

```
queryRequest: function (layer) {            
    if(layer!= null || layer!= undefined){                        
        var center = this.draw.getGeometry().getCenter();
        var radius = this.formatRadius();
        var latLong = this.getLatLong(center);    
        var latLongExtent = this.getLatLongExtent(latLong);
        var wfsUrl = layer.getWFSGetRequestUrl();                   
        console.log("Feature Url :"+wfsUrl);
        wfsUrl = wfsUrl+"&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(geometry,POINT("+latLongExtent+"),"+radius+")";                
//It should return only one value ..."travel_num":4727.
//wfsUrl ="http://geoserver.saartha.net:7070/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=saartha:s03travel&outputFormat=json&srsname=EPSG:3857&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(geometry,POINT(76.78399222656249%2013.47409553818946),27.71,kilometers)"

                console.log("Feature Url :"+wfsUrl);
                var request = new ProxyRequest().get(wfsUrl,{
                    version:'1.0.0',
                });
                request.then(lang.hitch(this,"readFeatures"))
                console.log("Request Url :"+request);
            }               
        },

## Heading ##

//converting to lat and long.
----------

 getLatLong :function(extentCircle){
    var latLong=[];
    var coord=[];
    coord=[extentCircle[0],extentCircle[1]];        
    var convertedVal = ol.proj.transform(coord,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326' );                
    latLong.push(convertedVal[0],convertedVal[1]);
    return latLong;
    },

getLatLongExtent: function (latLong) {
    var latLongExtent=latLong[0]+" "+latLong[1];            
    console.log("LAT-LONG :"+latLongExtent);            
    return latLongExtent;
    },

formatRadius: function () {
    var radius; 
    if ( this.draw != undefined && this.draw != null) 
    {
        var center = this.draw.getGeometry().getCenter();
        var endPoint = [center[0], center[1] + this.draw.getGeometry().getRadius()];
        var sourceProj = this.mapObj.getView().getProjection(); 
        var c1 = ol.proj.transform(center, sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326'); 
        var c2 = ol.proj.transform(endPoint, sourceProj,'EPSG:4326'); 
        radius = this.wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2); 
    } else {
        radius = Math.round(this.draw.getGeometry().getRadius() * 100) / 100; 
    }

    var output; 
    if (radius > 100) { 
       output = (Math.round(radius / 1000 * 100) / 100) + ' , ' + 'kilometers'; 
    }  else   { 
       output = (Math.round(radius * 100) / 100) + ' , ' + 'meters'; 
    } 
    return output; 
    },
    //reading the features.
    readFeatures: function (response) {
        var feature = this.geoJsonformat.readFeatures(response);
            console.log("feature :"+feature);
        },
```

Comment: What if the native SRS of your WFS FeatureType? I would guess that kilometers as units do not work like you want with POINT(76.78399 13.47409) but radius that is used is really 27.71 degrees.

Comment: no ,i have refered from ,below site please have a look:  https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WFS+-+Filter+-+Disjoint   . Native srs is EPSG:3857 only.

Comment: WFS 1.0.0 supports only native SRS by the standard. Some implementations have added support for srsName from WFS 1.1.0 but I would not trust in that. You say that this query is returning all the features `http://geoserver.saartha.net:7070/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=saartha:s03travel&outputFormat=json&srsname=EPSG:3857&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(geometry,POINT(76.78399222656249%2013.47409553818946),27.71,kilometers)`?

Answer (score 1):

The DWITHIN CQL_FILTER does look OK for me, though with some issues. DWITHIN=1 shows one state

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=351&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-124.731422,15.078543676470591,-66.969849,59.249158323529414&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN%28the_geom,POINT%28-103.46408902178649%2039.61777403594771%29,1,meters%29

[image]

DWITHIN=3 shows more states

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=351&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-124.731422,15.078543676470591,-66.969849,59.249158323529414&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN%28the_geom,POINT%28-103.46408902178649%2039.61777403594771%29,,meters%29

[image]

There is a GeoServer issue in that it is compulsory to give a unit like meter or kilometer but actually analysis is made by using unit=degree which is the native unit for EPSG:4326. That should not be your issue because your data is in EPSG:3857 and in any case the filter works but it is using other unit than the given one. You must have an error in some other place.

This is the GetFeature for the fist case:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.0.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN%28the_geom,POINT%28-103.46408902178649%2039.61777403594771%29,1,meters%29

Comment: Thanku sir, I am getting if i pass the radius in dgrees, but the I have on doubt about the map projection, What should be its projection, mine is set as EPSG:3857.